# Cyclic dependency with two LineEdits set text to each other

Tags: qt, qt-signals

I have two QLineEdits connected to each other so when the user enters text in one QLineEdit, the text in the other also changes and vice versa.

e.g.

```
connect(line_edit1, SIGNAL(textChanged()), line_edit2, SLOT(setText())
connect(line_edit2, SIGNAL(textChanged()), line_edit1, SLOT(setText())
```

The problem is that this causes an infinite loop because the textChanged() signal is emitted every time the text is set.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't think that it can work like you want when connected directly. You may need to create a step in between.

Answer (score 1):

Use the signal `textEdited` instead of `textChanged`.

It is only triggered by user action according to the doc :
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#textEdited
Then your call to `setText()` will not trigger the signal.